# Magento 2, Can't Enable WYSIWYG on description attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, magento-2.1.7, wysiwyg

I'm trying to enable the WYSIWYG editor, on the `description` product attribute. Magento ver. 2.1.7.

I've enabled the WYSIWYG in **Store > Attributes > Product > description**

[image]

Our Product `description` attribute type is `Text Area`

I've also enabled the wysiwyg for everywhere else, and it is working on CMS Pages & Blocks.

**Store > Configuration > General > Content Management > Enable wysiwyg.**

But still the Product `description` attribute does not have the wysiwyg enabled.  I've cleared the cache, re-indexed, compiled & deployed from the Magento CLI.  There are no JS errors in the browser console.

Am I missing something?